# Rear Bike Rack for Full Suspension?

Tags: compatibility, rack, full-suspension, giant

I have a Giant Warp DS3 and id like to get a rear rack but am struggling to find anything decent & compatible. 
is there such a rack?

[2001 Giant Warp DS3](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=35598&make=683&model=52870) from Bicycle Blue Book.

[image]

Comment: Can you include a photo of your bike so we can see how its set up?  I've included a photo from googling, but if that doesn't match your bike then please revert and replace it.

Answer (score 4):

You can get racks, what you get will largely depend on the load. The two styles that work are a seat post mount rack or once that clamps to the seat stay. Seatposts often have a low load limit, and can be prone to swinging around, but are generally very popular. Using on on a carbon frame would have to be done with caution - ensure a long seat post insertion.  For heavier loads, a frame mounted rack such as the Thule Pack'n Pedal is best.

A post rack puts all the extra weight on the rear suspension, so has the advantage its suspended, but you might need to adjust shock settings for an ideal ride. A rear triangle mount is un-suspended weight, and will not affect shock settings as much.

Answer (score 2):

This [instructables posting](https://www.instructables.com/id/Bike-rack-for-full-suspension-mountain-bike/) explains how. You attach a regular rack to the Axle and to the rear diagonal stay

[image]

Comment: +1 That's quite a neat solution.  This example is using rim brake bosses and the brakes are disks.  However I'd not carry much weight on this - a couple of pizzas at most, there's nothing much to limit side-to-side motion of the load.  On the plus side, this one doesn't interfere with the suspension pivots at all.

Answer (score 1):

The intended use of full suspension bikes does not really overlap with carrying luggage around on a rear mounted rack.

You can't fit a on the rear triangle, and there are no mounting points, and the triangle is really not designed for it.

There are seat post mounted racks but as @mattnz says they are load limited as the are cantilevered off the seat post. Depending on what you are trying to carry, an oversize seat bag may work for you.